# Desktop extends past TV screen

Tags: extended-desktop

MONITOR & TV HELP PLEASE:

I am trying to connect my tv as a second viewing screen (extended display). The trouble is the display extends past the tv.
Which settings do I need to use?
Does it have anything to do with the graphic card?
TV recommended settings are 1360 x 768
Monitor reccommended settings are 1920 x 1080 (1680 x 1050 fills the monitor perfectly).
If I mirror the 2 they are both okay.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change resolution of each device it is recommended settings. You don't need to have the setting match on TV and Monitor, additionally depending on your TV type you might need to adjust the setting on TV it self to properly display the image.

It would really help if you specify:

Operating System?
Connection used for each one? DVI, HDMI, VGA?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the extended display on the tv matches the recommended resolution.  When extending, your monitor settings can be whatever you like but the tv settings should match the tv to avoid these problems.  You may need to click on the tv in the monitors/display settings to see the resolution that it's set to from your computer.

Sometimes tvs also have some issues with overscan.  This is model dependent but a general example can be found here: http://www.katescomment.com/tv-monitor-how-to-fix-overscan-zoom/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the aspect ratio on your monitor is not an appropriate solution.  Rescaling means the picture is not displaying its original image.  Use this to make sure all the boundaries are proper: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S7SLep244ss

YOUR MONITOR SHOULD BE IN NORMAL ASPECT RATIO!!!

I have an NVIDA card.  I went to NVIDIA Control Panel and changed the resolution from there.  The apply button looks like it's disabled, but it's not.  After I did that, the TV would not allow me to change the aspect ratio with the WIDE button (Sony).  That's when I knew I had solved it.  Every monitor will be different but this is definitely a software issue.  Do not adjust your television set.  We control the horizontal and the vertical.  We can deluge you with 1000 images or expand one image to crystal clarity.